# array to string conversion error when retrieving location from facebook graph api

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array, foreach

The code for controller while using facebook login. Here, on requesting location, i do get the value from facebook. But the problem is when i feed location info on view page where i only need name not id. It says error on array to string conversion.

```
{
"id": "1069347886434951",
"name": "Saugat Thapa",
"location": {
"id": "106085869430478",
"name": "Kathmandu, Nepal"
   }
}



public function web_login()
{
    $data['user'] = array();

    // Check if user is logged in
    if ($this->facebook->is_authenticated())
    {
        // User logged in, get user details
        $location= $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=location{id,name}');
        if (!isset($user['error']))
        {
            $data['location'] = $location;
        }

    }

    // display view
    $this->load->view('examples/web', $data);
}
```

on view

```
 <?php foreach ($location as $key => $value) : ?>

                <li><?php echo $key; ?> : <?php echo $value; ?></li>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: <li><?php var_dump($key); ?> : <?php echo var_dup($value); ?></li>

Comment: and tell us what you got

Comment: ok i got the values i wanted. string(8) "location" : array(2) { ["name"]=> string(16) "Kathmandu, Nepal" ["id"]=> string(15) "106085869430478" } AND string(2) "id" : string(16) "1069347886434951"

Comment: i only want to feed kathmandu, nepal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this `<?php echo $value; ?>` to this `<?php echo $value['name']; ?>`

code goes in here

```
<?php  break; ?> // break
```

break out of the loop because the next element in the array is a string and it will produce an error `illegal string offset` and as you want only the name it's fine

Comment: i got the value printed but it comes up with additional error saying `Illegal string offset 'name'`

Comment: replace double quotes by single quotes '' and tell me what you got

Comment: i have used single quote, not double quote

Comment: it should be working fine ! ok use double quotes instead

Comment: it won't hurt trying

Comment: print_r($value); and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117967/discussion-between-saugat-thapa-and-ahmad-ghoneim).